# Plural vs Singular agreement

Tags: grammatical-number

The sentence is:

> Where there is beer, there **are** good times.

Shouldn't it be this?

> Where there is beer, there **is** good times.

Comment: Why? Would you say *Where there is a playground, there is children*?

Comment: No, but if they were contracted, they'd both be _there's_. Subject agreement goes with the original subject, not the dummy _there_. _There_-Insertion splits the subject properties among two NPs -- the original subject governs agreement, but the dummy _there_ acts as subject with respect to Raising (e.g, _There is expected to be rain tonight_ from _`Indef` expects there to be rain tonight_).

Answer (score 2):

No, the first sentence is correct.

The rule in English is:

- If the subject is singular, use "is".
- If the subject is plural (i.e. not singular), use "are".

So in this instance, you would apply the second dot point as "good times" is plural - notice the "s".

Comment: The trouble is that the verb agrees with its **Subject**, not just with any old word. So if the subject is singular, use _is_; if plural, _are_. True. But which word's the subject? The one in the subject position before the verb, or the one after the verb? For agreement, it's the one after the verb; for other subject properties, it's the dummy _there_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you for the tips. I designed the rule so that it could be applied to both.